# How to change a component's state correctly from another component as a login method executes?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components - a sign in form component that holds the form and handles login logic, and a progress bar similar to the one on top here in SO. I want to be able to show my progress bar fill up as the login logic executes if that makes sense, so as something is happening show the user an indication of loading. I've got the styling sorted I just need to understand how to correctly trigger the functions.

I'm new to React so my first thought was to define `handleFillerStateMax()` and `handleFillerStateMin()` within my `ProgressBarComponent` to perform the state changes. As the state changes it basically changes the width of the progress bar, it all works fine. But how do I call the functions from `ProgressBarComponent` as my `Login` component `onSubmit` logic executes? I've commented my ideas but they obviously don't work..

`ProgressBarComponent`:

```
class ProgressBarComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            percentage: 0
        }
    }

    // the functions to change state
    handleFillerStateMax = () => {
        this.setState ({percentage: 100})
    }

    handleFillerStateMin = () => {
        this.setState ({percentage: 0})
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ProgressBar percentage={this.state.percentage}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`Login` component:

```
class SignInFormBase extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {...INITIAL_STATE};
    }

    onSubmit = event => {

        const {email, password} = this.state;

        // ProgressBarComponent.handleFillerMax()????

        this.props.firebase
            .doSignInWithEmailAndPass(email,password)
            .then(()=> {
                this.setState({...INITIAL_STATE});
                this.props.history.push('/');

                //ProgressBarComponent.handleFillerMin()????

            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({error});
            })
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: To integrate progress bar on page change, you should use some sort of page routing solution, for example, nextjs which gives you methods when page change starts and when page change is completed. `Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => { // progress start }; Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => { // progress end }; `

Comment: Not necessarily on page change, I want it to progress as my logic executes. So for example when i used vanilla JS i used to put a spinner in the DOM, hide it, and show it only during logic execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrase what you're doing. Not "setting the progress bar's progress" but "modifying the applications state such that the progress bar will re-render with new data".

1. Keep the current progress in the state of the parent of `SignInFormBase` and `ProgressBarComponent`, and pass it to `ProgressBarComponent` as a prop so it just renders what it is told. Unless there is some internal logic omitted from `ProgressBar` that handles its own progress update; is there?
2. Pass in a callback to `SignInFormBase` that it can call when it has new information to report: that is, replace `ProgressBarComponent.handleFillerMax()` with `this.props.reportProgress(100)` or some such thing. The callback should `setState({progress: value})`.

Now, when the `SignInFormBase` calls the `reportProgress` callback, it sets the state in the parent components. This state is passed in to `ProgressBarComponent` as a prop, so the fact that it changed will cause he progress bar to re-render.

Requested example for #2, something like the following untested code:

```
class App extends Component {
  handleProgressUpdate(progress) {
    this.setState({progress: progress});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyRootElement>
        <ProgressBar progress={this.state.progress} />
        <LoginForm onProgressUpudate={(progress) => this.handleProgressUpdate(progress)} />
      </MyRootElemen>
    )
  }
}
```

The simply call `this.props.onProgressUpdate(value)` from `LoginForm` whenever it has new information that should change the value.

Comment: For step 1 I would set the state in `App.js` (I'm using create-react-app). Can you give a code example for step 2 please?

Comment: Added a quick & dirty example.

Comment: Thanks. I've got a `<Router>` setup thus `<Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>`. How can I combine your prop syntax with my route structure?

Comment: Thanks, figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

In basic terms, this is the sort of structure to go for (using `useState` for brevity but it could of course be a class-based stateful component if you prefer):

```
const App = ()=> {
    const [isLoggingIn, setIsLoggingIn] = useState(false)
    const handleOnLoginStart = () => {
       setIsLoggingIn(true)
    }
    const handleOnLoginSuccess = () => {
       setIsLoggingIn(false)
    }
    <div>
       <ProgressBar percentage={isLoggingIn?0:100}/>
       <LoginForm onLoginStart={handleOnLogin} onLoginSuccess={handleOnLoginSuccess}/>
    </div>

}
```

In your LoginForm you would have:

```
onSubmit = event => {

    const {email, password} = this.state;

    this.props.onLoginStart() // <-- call the callback

    this.props.firebase
        .doSignInWithEmailAndPass(email,password)
        .then(()=> {
            this.setState({...INITIAL_STATE});
            this.props.history.push('/');

            this.props.onLoginSuccess() // <-- call the callback


        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({error});
        })
    event.preventDefault();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I followed Andrew's instructions but yours is quite similar

Comment: Cheers. One thing to note is that my approach keeps the Login component decoupled from the concept of 'progress'. It just calls callbacks at different stages, which makes it more reusable.